# Get Current Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I get the current Google Map that is already initialized on the page with the Javascript V3 api, so I can reset a marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the map object in javascript as global then you get the anywhere in javascript

Comment: I will do that, but there isn't a way from the Google Javascript API?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a marker and you want to reference the map that it relates to you can simply call `getMap()` on the marker.

```
var myMap = myMarker.getMap();
```

When called from an object it returns the map on which the object is rendered/displayed.
This is true for most objects in the google.maps namespace (Marker, Polyline, Rectangle, etc).

If you take a look through the [reference page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) you can see which objects `getMap()` is an available method for.